# jQuery Create array with atribute data and checked (true/false)

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, checked

I Should create function, where with this markup

```
<ul id="#list">
  <li data-id="22"><input type="checkbox" data-id="22" checked></li>
  <li data-id="32"><input type="checkbox" data-id="32"></li>
  <li data-id="56"><input type="checkbox" data-id="56"></li>
  <li data-id="43"><input type="checkbox" data-id="43" checked></li>
</ul>
```

Return me data-id:true/false of checkbox checked

```
object: Array
22:true
32:false
56:false
43:true
```

I have this function

```
function () {
            return $('#list')
                .find('li')
                .map(function (i, el) {
                    return $(el).data('categoryid');
                })
                .get();
}
```

where return i:data-id (but data-id of li)
How should I modify this code?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/gw8h2f5q/

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ul` id should be `list` and not `#list`

Then do

```
var obj = {};
$("#list").each(function(){
   obj[$(this).data("id")]=this.checked;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to add  a `#` in the element's markup id:

```
<ul id="list"><!-- remove # -->
```

then you can try something like this:

```js
var arr = [];

$('#list :checkbox').each(function(i, el){ 
  arr[i] = $(el).data('id') + ' : '+this.checked; 
});

$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li data-id="22">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="22" checked>
  </li>
  <li data-id="32">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="32">
  </li>
  <li data-id="56">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="56">
  </li>
  <li data-id="43">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="43" checked>
  </li>
</ul>

<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you

This is my code based on this

```
        var a = {};
        var functionList = function(i, el) { 
            a[$(el).data('id')] = this.checked; };
        $('#list :checkbox').each(functionList);
        return a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following piece of code for the expected result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var arr =  $('li').map(function() 
{ 
 return ($(this).data("id") + ":" + ($(this).children().is(":checked")))
})
.get();
console.log(arr)
});
```